# unable to change form field label in django

Tags: django, forms, label

I'm trying to change the label name of a form field in django, but it won't change. I've changed all instances of the word throughout my code, but still it remains what it originally was. Do I have to delete the form and rewrite it or is there another way to force django to reflect the code?

Comment: Just use `label` attribute of your form field. Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#label

Comment: @oz19 Thank you, you are correct and solved my problem, could you kindly post this as an answer so I can upvote you and mark as the answer please.

Comment: I'm glad to know that it worked. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `label` attribute of your form field.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myField = forms.CharField(label='My new label')
```

From Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#label).